# i am not able to view my downloaded file in downloads folder using selenium java

Tags: java

[Screenshot displaying the downloaded file in a window[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmmBw.jpg)i am not able to access my downloaded file which i opened in a new small window popup using selenium java and also i am not able to find it in downloads folder.
When i **click on a download button-->the file gets downloaded with an icon of word in a new small popup browser window-->but it does not move into the downloads folder**. Testcase passes but i am not able to validate.In that browser window i am not able to find any elements....only .... tags are displayed.. While doing it in manual way i am able to view it in downloads folder. 
Kindly advise me what should be done.

Comment: post your code too.

Comment: How can `access my downloaded file` relate to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you are coding in `java` language,
so, use method `exists()` which will return boolean value.
You must know your Downloaded file name along with exact download path,

```
String FileName = "YOUR_FILE_NAME";
File tmpDir = new File("C:\Users\a.k\Downloads\"+FileName);
if(tmpDir.exists())
    System.out.println("File Downloaded");
System.out.println("File Not Downloaded");
```